# Skiasharp spin the wheel game . two object collusion

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I am learning skiasharp and doing a spin the wheel game .
I managed successfully to draw a divided circle into six segments with different colors and make it spin for 10 seconds .

what I want to do now but i am failing at it and maybe I can get your take and opinion . 
I want when the circle stop spinning to choose a color that the pin is inside it .

I tried to search for skiasharp collusion but no luck .

Here is my code .

My spin.cs :

```
public partial class Spin : ContentPage
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        bool _pageIsActive;
        float _degrees;

        class ChartData
        {
            public ChartData(int value, SKColor color)
            {
                Value = value;
                Color = color;
            }

            public int Value { private set; get; }

            public SKColor Color { private set; get; }
        }

        ChartData[] chartData =
        {
            new ChartData(10, SKColors.Red),
            new ChartData(10, SKColors.Green),
            new ChartData(10, SKColors.Blue),
            new ChartData(10, SKColors.Magenta),
            new ChartData(10, SKColors.Cyan),
            new ChartData(10, SKColors.Brown)
        };
        public Spin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            _pageIsActive = true;
        }
        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();
            _pageIsActive = false;
        }
        async Task AnimationLoop()
        {
            stopwatch.Reset();
            stopwatch.Start();

            while (_pageIsActive && stopwatch.Elapsed < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
            {
                skiaView.InvalidateSurface();
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / 90));
            }
            stopwatch.Stop();

        }
        void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args)
        {
            IncrementDegrees();

            SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
            SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
            SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

            var x1 = info.Width / 6;
            var x2 = info.Width / 3 + x1;
            var x3 = info.Width / 3 * 2 + x1;
            var y = info.Height / 2;
            int _squareWidth = Math.Min(info.Width, info.Height) / 10;

            canvas.Clear();

            int totalValues = 0;

            foreach (ChartData item in chartData)
            {
                totalValues += item.Value;
            }

            SKPoint center = new SKPoint(info.Width / 2, info.Height / 2);
            float explodeOffset = 50;
            float radius = Math.Min(info.Width / 2, info.Height / 2) - 2 * explodeOffset;
            SKRect rect = new SKRect(center.X - radius, center.Y - radius,
                                     center.X + radius, center.Y + radius);

            float startAngle = 0;

            foreach (ChartData item in chartData)
            {
                float sweepAngle = 360f * item.Value / totalValues;

                using (SKPath path = new SKPath())
                using (SKPaint fillPaint = new SKPaint())
                using (SKPaint outlinePaint = new SKPaint())
                using (var path3 = new SKPath())
                {
                    path.MoveTo(center);
                    path.ArcTo(rect, startAngle, sweepAngle, false);
                    path.Close();

                    fillPaint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill;
                    fillPaint.Color = item.Color;

                    outlinePaint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke;
                    outlinePaint.StrokeWidth = 5;
                    outlinePaint.Color = SKColors.Black;

                    canvas.Save();

                    // Fill and stroke the path
                    //canvas.DrawPath(path, fillPaint);
                   // canvas.DrawPath(path, outlinePaint);


                    var cx3 = x3 - _squareWidth / 2;
                    var cy3 = y + _squareWidth / 2;
                    path3.MoveTo(cx3, cy3);
                    path3.LineTo(cx3 + _squareWidth, cy3);
                    path3.LineTo(cx3 + _squareWidth, cy3 - _squareWidth);
                    path3.LineTo(cx3, cy3 - _squareWidth);
                    path3.LineTo(cx3, cy3);
                    DrawRotatedWithMatrices(canvas, path, fillPaint, outlinePaint, _degrees, (int)center.X, y);
                    canvas.Restore();


                }

                startAngle += sweepAngle;
            }
            canvas.RotateDegrees(90);
        }
        private void IncrementDegrees()
        {
            _degrees += 3.5f;

            if (_degrees >= 360)
            {
                _degrees = 0;
            }
        }
        void DrawRotatedWithMatrices(SKCanvas canvas, SKPath path, SKPaint fill,SKPaint outline ,float degrees, int cx, int cy)
        {
            var result = SKMatrix.MakeIdentity();
            var translate = SKMatrix.MakeTranslation(-cx, -cy);
            var rotate = SKMatrix.MakeRotationDegrees(degrees);
            var translate2 = SKMatrix.MakeTranslation(cx, cy);

            SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref result, translate);
            SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref result, rotate);
            SKMatrix.PostConcat(ref result, translate2);

            path.Transform(result);
            canvas.DrawPath(path, fill);
            canvas.DrawPath(path, outline);
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _pageIsActive = true;

            AnimationLoop();

        }

        private void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _pageIsActive = false;

        }
    }
```

My spin.xaml

```
<StackLayout x:Name="viewx">
                <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="skiaView" PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurface" HeightRequest="500" WidthRequest="500"/>

            </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [SKPath.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skpath.contains?view=skiasharp-1.68.0#SkiaSharp_SKPath_Contains_System_Single_System_Single_)

> Returns true if the point (x, y) is contained by the path, taking into
>   account the FillType.

Comment: It works .However i got into another issue . In my code i am using only one path to draw 6 arcs inside a foreach loop . with this i am only able to use SKpath.contain with the last path drawn . so I tried to use an array of paths and here where I got another problem , im trying to define the path array like this :                 using (SKPath[] path = new SKPath[6])
but i get an error :
SKPath[]: type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Comment: if you have a new problem you need to ask a new question

Comment: If you want to read the data from the paths after it is drawn, you can't dispose them - reading it will result in a crash as they are no longer around. Also, for that case you are disposing an ARRAY of paths - not the paths themselves.

Comment: The angle calculation worked pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

What you could also do is not care about the actual drawing for your case. Since each segment is equal, just do all the animations and things. Then, when the spin has stopped, check the rotation and use basic division to get the color.

For example, you have 6 segments:

```
ChartData[] chartData =
{
    new ChartData(10, SKColors.Red),
    new ChartData(10, SKColors.Green),
    new ChartData(10, SKColors.Blue),
    new ChartData(10, SKColors.Magenta),
    new ChartData(10, SKColors.Cyan),
    new ChartData(10, SKColors.Brown)
};
```

Just do a basic (pseudo code):

```
var segment = (rotationInDegrees / 360f) * chartData.Length;
var data = chartData[segement];
var color = data.Color;
```

That way, you can do all sorts of fancy filters/gradients and whatnot to the UI, and then always get the basic color using simple math.

Comment: This segment is reliable. It must be made an int though.